Proper alternative to using StringArrayPropertyEditor(null) for handling commas in String array request parameters
I have the following endpoint:

    @GetMapping(value = "/{siteId}/articles")
    public Flux<ServerSentEvent<MyObj>> getArticleRevenueForSite(
            @PathVariable UUID siteId,
            @RequestParam(name = "names") @Validated @NotEmpty String[] names) {
        
        // ...
    }

My problem is the following:
I would like to provide a list of query parameters for this endpoint as a filter. For example:
GET /v1/sites/<id>/articles?name=Cola

This works as expected. However, some of my names have special characters in them including ,. This causes the following:
GET /v1/sites/<id>/articles?name=Cola 0,25

even when URL encoded as name=Cola%200%2C25 to be interpreted as two separate values.
This problem has lots of similar StackOverflow questions. For brevity, one possible solution (linked here) is the following:
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String[].class, new StringArrayPropertyEditor(null));
    }

This works. In this case, I can do:
GET /v1/sites/<id>/articles?name=Cola%200%2C25

for single values and:
GET /v1/sites/<id>/articles?name=Cola%200%2C25&name=Fanta

for multiple values, yielding ["Cola 0,25"] and ["Cola 0,25", "Fanta"] respectively, as desired.
However, Spring core's StringArrayPropertyEditor only accepts null due to a formality: the getAsText method (which is not used when binding request params, from what I can tell) does not actually accept a null parameter and would produce an NPE if it were ever called.
From what I can see, though this solution is the most concise and elegant (because it is confined to my single controller that has need of this functionality), this technically only works because of (what might ostensibly be construed as) a bug in Spring core's StringArrayPropertyEditor which makes it allow a null values for the separator.
I would rather not fully rely on this behaviour not changing in the future and would appreciate some insight as to whether this should be fine to use or not...
